# Finding the components of a vector along two other vectors

Tags: statics

[image]

Using only the diagram above (Not using the questions in the diagram), i am asked to find the components of F2 along F1 and F3.

I am having trouble with this question. I can easily resolve any of the vectors into their x and y components but I am not 100% certain how to resolve it along the other vectors. Am I correct in saying that to resolve F2 along F1 we draw a line down directly from the head of F2 to F1 and then take 750*Cos(45) to get the component parallel to F1. What should I do to resolve F2 along F3?

The answer is given as 1240N and 884N. Any hints on how to get to those answers would be much appreciated. Perhaps I am not understanding what is meant by resolving a vector along another vector?

Comment: To be clear, you need to something different from the questions posed in the displayed questions, right? Because 2-36 and 2-37 aren't asking for that.

Comment: This link has a way, but when I tried it I did not get the answers you posted in the question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286391/find-the-component-of-veca-along-vecb

Answer (score 1):

[image]

From the geometry $a_1=45 {}^{\circ}$ and $a_2=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)$ are known and $c_1$ and $c_2$ need to be determined.

They can be obtained by solving the following two equations

$$ 750 \cos \left(a_1\right)-c_2 \cos \left(a_2\right)=c_1$$

$$ c_2 \sin \left(a_2\right)+750 \sin \left(a_1\right)=0$$

This will give $$ c_1=875 \sqrt{2}=1237.44$$ and $$ c_2=-625 \sqrt{2}=-883.883$$